I know the following language is undecidable by reduction to HP bar. But how does it relate to L_EQ?
The languages are defined as such (for standard Turing machines and over $\{0, 1\}^*$:
$$
L_3 \triangleq \{
(\langle M \rangle, x) \mid \text{$\forall M^\prime, [x\in L(M^\prime)] \lor [\langle M^\prime\rangle \in L(M)]$}
\}
$$
Where the definition of $L_{EQ}$ is the following:
$$
L_{EQ} =\{
(\langle M_1 \rangle, \langle M_2 \rangle) \mid L(M_1) = L(M_2)
\}
$$
It was relatively easy for me to compose a reduction $\overline{HP} \leq L_3$ to show that $L_3 \notin RE$, but out of curiosity I tried to find whether $L_{EQ} \leq L_3$, and could not find a working reduction.
I was wondering if such a reduction even exists, or if it could be that $L_{EQ}$ is actually a "harder" language.
In general, I found that making reductions from $L_{EQ}$ was nearly impossible for me to achieve, and I'm wondering if there's any good reason for that other than the potential lack of technique.
Thanks in advance!
